# local variable referenced before assignment even when doing assignment

Tags: python

I had a recursive version of the knapsack problem and got a local variable referenced before assignment error. But isn't it ok given that the statement of `max_with_inclusion = recursive ...` is itself an assignment? Generally I am used to assigning variables in python like that where no type information is required. Can someone explain the problem here.

```
def recursive_max_helper(knapsack_max_weight,items,index,max_so_far):
    if index == len(items):
        return max_so_far
    # Uncomment removes error max_with_inclusion = max_with_exclusion = 0
    if knapsack_max_weight - items[index].weight >= 0:
        max_with_inclusion = recursive_max_helper(knapsack_max_weight - items[index].weight,items,index+1,max_so_far+items[index].value) 
    max_with_exclusion = recursive_max_helper(knapsack_max_weight,items,index+1,max_so_far)
    return max(max_with_exclusion,max_with_inclusion)


tests = [
    {
        'correct_output': 14,
        'input':
            {
                'knapsack_max_weight': 15,
                'items': [Item(10, 7), Item(9, 8), Item(5, 6)]}},
    {
        'correct_output': 13,
        'input':
            {
                'knapsack_max_weight': 25,
                'items': [Item(10, 2), Item(29, 10), Item(5, 7), Item(5, 3), Item(5, 1), Item(24, 12)]}}]
for test in tests:
    assert test['correct_output'] == recursive_max_value(**test['input'])
```

Comment: could it be that it tries to return max_with_inclusion without being referenced?

Answer (score 3):

`max_with_inclusion` only gets set if your `if` condition evaluates to `True`. So no, the variable is not set when `knapsack_max_weight < items[index].weight`.

Two simple solutions:

1. Pre-assign in all cases, as your comment suggests.
2. Add an `else` clause to make sure `max_with_inclusion` gets set.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` block isn't guaranteed to run, so `max_with_inclusion` isn't guaranteed to exist. When you call `max` you get it referenced before assignment. Initialize the var with some value prior to the `if` block or in an `else` block, like `max_with_inclusion = -1` or whatever makes sense for a default.

Comment: Max_with_exclusion does not have such issues right ?

Comment: Correct, it evaluates every time.